# Chrome/firefox extension to read data streaming over USB and network to localhost

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm looking at the possibility of using a chrome extension or firefox addon that will allow me to read information that is sent over USB in the form of text data? And to the localhost/IP of the machine to certain port?

Can someone point me to the any examples or API documents that will help with my search?

The idea be that the extension is listening for text data on USB or to the localhost of the machine.

Thanks  in advance

Additional information:

Can an extension listen to traffic being set over a local IP? on a certain port? Can it be sent to localhost?

Can you listen to data being sent over a USB port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome the browser will not provide such access to the system.
The correct way would be to have an external program collecting the data and communicating with the browser add-on. It is achieved through [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging).

Note that you will not be able to bundle the external program with the extension; you'll need to have your own installer.

Edit: I have to comment that @abraham's answer is perhaps more correct. You can have raw USB access in a context of a Packaged App.

Answer (score 4):

There is [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) for interacting with USB devices. It is only accessible in Chrome apps however and not extensions.